# @EJB used from within JAX-RS service on Bluemix

Tags: ejb, jax-rs, ibm-cloud

I have a following project structure:

EARproject
RESTproject
EJBproject
where EAR project bundels RESTproject and EJBproject.

In the RESTproject I have a service in which I would like to use an EJB (Stateless, Local) implemented in the EJBproject. The EJB is defined in the ejb-jar.xml

I assumed I can use @EJB annotation inside the REST service. In the RESTproject there is a reference to the EJB in the web.xml.

When using @EJB annotation the EJB reference is always null. I have also tried to implement the EJB inside the RESTproject i the same package as the REST service but still no joy.

How can I obtain a handle of the EJB from within a REST service?

Comment: Interestingly, when this is deployed into a local instance of WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile then @EJB annotation provides a reference to an EJB Instance. Any idea someone?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you need to annotate your REST Service with @Stateless annotation in order to be able to inject a resource using @EJB, @Inject, @PersistenceUnit and so on. This [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jee6/entry/getting_ejb_inside_a_jax_rs_service?lang=en) helped me to resolve.